# Freeze specific items in list

Tags: python

i don't know how i can make some (not all) items frozen in a normal list. I am generating a binairy puzzle in a twodimentional list in python. but i don't know how i can make the ones that are generated immutable, so when the suer plays the game he can not change the generated pieces in the puzzle.

sorry for dutch coding. I'm a student

i don't know what to try. i was thinking of making a dictionary with the locations and let the program check every time the suer changes a tile in the game. but i don't think that will be effective.

```
import random
import string

alfabet = list(string.ascii_uppercase)

def limit(number, mini, maxi):
    return max(min(maxi, number), mini)

def game(grootte):
    # maak speelveld
    speelveld = []
    for i in range(0, grootte):
        rij = []
        for x in range(0, grootte):
            rij.append('.')
        speelveld.append(rij)

# vul speelveld
for i in range(0, grootte+4):
    errorcheck = False
    while errorcheck == False:
        r_binairy = random.randint(0, 1)
        r_location_a = random.randint(0, grootte-1)
        r_location_b = random.randint(0, grootte-1)

        errorcheck = speelveld[limit(r_location_a+1, 0, grootte-1)][limit(r_location_b, 0, grootte-1)] and speelveld[limit(r_location_a+2, 0, grootte-1)][limit(r_location_b, 0, grootte-1)] != r_binairy and \
        speelveld[limit(r_location_a-1, 0, grootte-1)][limit(r_location_b, 0, grootte-1)] and speelveld[limit(r_location_a-2, 0, grootte-1)][limit(r_location_b, 0, grootte-1)] != r_binairy and \
        speelveld[limit(r_location_a+1, 0, grootte-1)][limit(r_location_b, 0, grootte-1)] and speelveld[limit(r_location_a-1, 0, grootte-1)][limit(r_location_b, 0, grootte-1)] != r_binairy and \
        speelveld[limit(r_location_a, 0, grootte-1)][limit(r_location_b+1, 0, grootte-1)] and speelveld[limit(r_location_a, 0, grootte-1)][limit(r_location_b+2, 0, grootte-1)] != r_binairy and \
        speelveld[limit(r_location_a, 0, grootte-1)][limit(r_location_b-1, 0, grootte-1)] and speelveld[limit(r_location_a, 0, grootte-1)][limit(r_location_b-2, 0, grootte-1)] != r_binairy and \
        speelveld[limit(r_location_a, 0, grootte-1)][limit(r_location_b-1, 0, grootte-1)] and speelveld[limit(r_location_a, 0, grootte-1)][limit(r_location_b+1, 0, grootte-1)] != r_binairy

    speelveld[r_location_a][r_location_b] = r_binairy

# print speelveld
def print_speelveld():
    print("\n")
    teller = 1
    print('         A', end="")
    for i in range(0, grootte-1):
        print(' ', format(alfabet[teller], '>6'), end="")
        teller += 1
    print("\n")
    teller = 1
    for i in speelveld:
        print(format(teller, ' <4'), "|", end="")
        for x in i:
            print('', format(x , '^5'), '|', end="")
        print('\n')
        teller += 1

# speel spel
bord_niet_vol = True

while bord_niet_vol == True:
    print_speelveld()
    for i in speelveld:
        for x in i:
            if x == '.':
                bord_niet_vol = True
            else:
                bord_niet_vol = False

    vak = input('\ngeef het volgende in: RIJ KOLOM GETAL. Als voorbeeld "A10" (Kolom A, Rij 1, Getal 0). Gebruik HOOFDLETTERS\n\ninvoer: ')
    invoer = list(vak)
    invoer[0] = alfabet.index(invoer[0])
    invoer[1] = int(invoer[1])-1
    invoer[2] = int(invoer[2])
    speelveld[invoer[1]][invoer[0]] = invoer[2]
```

I would like to make this random generated board immutable but the "." changeable. But they SHOULD be changeable for a second time for if the user makes a mistake.

Comment: sorry for bad coding

Comment: Hello! Please post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). There are several undefined variables in what you have posted. And duch names does not help to understand what they should represent.

Answer (score -1):

I would setup a dictionary of `'index:givenvalues'` where value is a list of all possible values, (assuming not infinite!) but where the `len(givenvalues) == 1`, insert a break to prevent updates.